# How to add custom where condition in user listing at WordPress admin page?

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I have found a [posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter to add custom where conditions in listing posts. Like this is there any filter to add custom where condition for listing the users?

Answer (score 0):

Make a custome query like:

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = $page_id "));
 if($rows){
  echo "win";
```

}

But!

use get_row if you want to display 1 record.

If you display multiple recorsd use

```
$searchvalue = $wpdb->get_results("QUERY"); 
foreach($searchvalue as $sh)
{

}
```